# Can a template function deduce a lambda's arguments?

Tags: c++, lambda, metaprogramming, function-pointers, c++17

A templated function that takes a function pointer can deduce the arguments of that function pointer like this:

```
template<class... Args>
void func(void (*ptr)(Args&& ...)) {
    //Do something useful knowing the Args...
}
```

Can you do the same with a lambda as the argument;
without resorting to `std::function` or writing a metaprogramming traits class like a function_traits? i.e. deduce the arguments just using a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Template argument deduction can only deduce types, constants, and templates that are "compositionally" part of the argument types, for example, deducing `void` and `Args...` from `void(*)(Args&&...)` as in your example, or deducing `T` and `N` from `T(&)[N]`. It cannot deduce anything that doesn't appear in the type.

For a non-polymorphic lambda type `T`, the type of `&T::operator()` contains deducible information about the lambda's argument types. But `T` itself does not.

Comment: Does that mean you could write something like `decltype(&T::operator())(Args&&...)`as the argument to get the lambdas parameters, or is it strictly not possible?

Comment: @Brian Yes, if the lambda is not polymorphic, you can put `R (T::*)(Args...)` as the argument type and pass `&T::operator()` as the argument. A total of 8 overloads are needed to cover all the cases, as the lambda's `operator()` may either be or not be const-qualified, may either be or not be `noexcept`, and may either have or not have a trailing ellipsis.